# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Server Glances Installation

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

Did any one know how install Glances on fresh Server 18.04.1 LTS. Actually I can't find it on repo and I can't add it from outside repo. On Ubuntu 18.04 it's no problem to find and install it.

Comment: `glances` comes from the universe repo.  You might need to run `sudo apt-add-repository universe` to enable it so you can install it.

Comment: That's true, It's work, thanks for help. I haven't no idea that universe repository exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved adding universe repository `sudo apt-add-repository universe`